# What are the benefits of last rites to a mortally injured person in the Catholic belief?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, biblical-basis

If a person is a unbeliever and has been injured in a way that there is no hope of survival and has never accepted Jesus Christ as Savior, does the Catholic Church believe that last rites performed with this person will bring salvation to this person.  I understand that anyone can be saved upon their deathbed but suppose this person was unconscious and never regained consciousness, would last rites still be performed and belief that this would save the person's soul?

Of course this questions is geared towards the Catholic community and Church.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [*Catechism of the Council of Trent*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5864):

> #### The Effects of [Extreme Unction](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Unction.shtml)
>
> The advantages we receive from this Sacrament are also to be
> accurately explained, so that if nothing else can allure the faithful
> to its reception, they may be induced at least by its utility; for we
> are naturally disposed to measure almost all things by our interests.
>
> Pastors, therefore, should teach that by this Sacrament is imparted
> grace that remits sins, and especially lighter, or as they are
> commonly called, venial sins; for mortal sins are removed by the
> Sacrament of Penance. Extreme Unction was not instituted primarily for
> the remission of grave offences; only Baptism and Penance accomplish
> this directly.
>
> Another advantage of the Sacred Unction is that it liberates the soul
> from the languor and infirmity which it contracted from sins, and from
> all the other remains of sin. The time most opportune for this cure is
> when we are afflicted with severe illness and danger to life impends,
> for it has been implanted in man by nature to dread no human
> visitation so much as death. This dread is greatly augmented by the
> recollection of our past sins, especially if our conscience accuses us
> of grave offences; for it is written: They shall come with fear at the
> thought of their sins, and their iniquities shall stand against them
> to convict them. Another source of vehement anguish is the anxious
> thought that we must soon afterwards stand before the judgment seat of
> God, who will pass on us a sentence of strictest justice according to
> our deserts. It often happens that, struck with this terror, the
> faithful feel themselves deeply agitated; and nothing conduces more to
> a tranquil death than to banish sadness, await with a joyous mind the
> coming of our Lord, and be ready willingly to surrender the deposit
> entrusted whenever it shall be His will to demand it back. To free the
> minds of the faithful from this solicitude, and fill the soul with
> pious and holy joy is, then, an effect of the Sacrament of Extreme
> Unction.
>
> From it, moreover, we derive another advantage, which may justly be
> deemed the greatest of all. For although the enemy of the human race
> never ceases, while we live, to meditate our ruin and destruction, yet
> at no time does he more violently use every effort utterly to destroy
> us, and, if possible, deprive us of all hope of the divine mercy, than
> when he sees the last day of life approach. Therefore arms and
> strength are supplied to the faithful in this Sacrament to enable them
> to break the violence and impetuosity of the adversary, and to fight
> bravely against him; for the soul of the sick is relieved and
> encouraged by the hope of the divine goodness, strengthened by which
> it bears more lightly ail the burdens of sickness, and eludes with
> greater ease the artifice and cunning of the devil who lies in wait
> for it.
>
> Finally, the recovery of health, if indeed advantageous, is another
> effect of this Sacrament. And if in our days the sick obtain this
> effect less frequently, this is to be attributed, not to any defect of
> the Sacrament, but rather to the weaker faith of a great part of those
> who are anointed with the sacred oil, or by whom it is administered;
> for the Evangelist bears witness that the Lord wrought not many
> miracles among His own, because of their unbelief.
>
> It may also be truly said at the Christian religion, since it has
> struck its roots more deeply in the minds of men, stands now less in
> need of the aids of such miracles than it did formerly, at the
> commencement of the rising Church. Nevertheless, faith should be
> strongly excited in this respect, and whatever it may please God in
> His wisdom to do with regard to the health of the body, the faithful
> ought to rely on a sure hope of attaining, by virtue of this sacred
> oil, health of the soul, and of experiencing, should the hour of their
> departure from life be at hand, the fruit of that glorious assurance:
> Blessed are the dead who die in the Lord.

Comment: I would mention that the person would have to be baptized to receive the anointing of the sick.

Comment: I have a few ideas for possible improvement: Consider sourcing the quote from http://www.saintsbooks.net/books/The%20Roman%20Catechism.pdf which includes copyright status and English translation information. Try to summarize in your own words the essential points, with one or two short quotes. Mention that a Priest can comfort anyone that they are in the hands of a loving God, but clarify the limits on use of the actual sacrament.

Comment: @ Geremia.  Am I to understand this as the last rites are  to calm and reassure the dying?  Perhaps to give them their last opportunity to repent of unconfessed sins?  What about the unbeliever that is unconscious  would the last rites still be performed..?

Comment: @Littlemisspiper They cannot be performed on an an unconscious person. See the subsection: "The Subject Must Be In Danger Of Death" [here](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Unction.shtml).

Comment: @Belinda, why must one be baptized?  Can one not be saved or receive last rites without baptism?

Comment: @Geremia,  ah yes, I have much reading to do.  I'm  still new here, just figuring it all out.  You have been a great help

Comment: I think you have the information all here, but you really really need to do more for your answer than just dump in a quote. Your answer is almost 99% someone else's words.

Comment: @MattGutting Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Our Help section states, ["Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own."](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)